# How to Assign Multi Modifieries in PyQt KeypressEvent?,

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

How to Assign Multi Modifieries in PyQt KeypressEvent ?  If I use Single Modifier, its works. But With Two modifiers, nothing will display

```
def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.modifiers() == Qt.AltModifier and event.key() == Qt.Key_A:
            print(" You Press Alt + A")
        elif (event.modifiers() == Qt.AltModifier and event.modifiers() == Qt.ControlModifier) and event.key() == Qt.Key_A:
            print("you Press Alt+ctrl+A")
```

Comment: Those are binary flags, use the `&` operator.

Comment: & operator , also not work for me @musicamante

Comment: It didn't work because you probably used it wrong. If you need an exact comparison of a *composition* then you either use `if modifiers == (Ctrl | Alt)` which is *not* the same as `if modifiers & Ctrl and modifiers & Alt`, which is instead a *match*.

Answer (score 1):

Pipe character , solve the problem

```
  if event.modifiers() == Qt.AltModifier and event.key() == Qt.Key_F:
            print(" You Press Alt + F")
        elif (event.modifiers() == Qt.AltModifier | Qt.ControlModifier) and event.key() == Qt.Key_F:
            print("you Press Alt+ctrl+F")
```